# Unable to stream to file that was unlinked

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating a system in which I need to cache a file in a short amount of time, and then delete it. I'm running into an error that if I try to cache the same deleted file after deletion, I get a permission error.

I have made a reproduction of my problem, and it looks like this:

```
//@ts-check
const fs = require("fs")
const promisify = require("util").promisify
const unlink = promisify(fs.unlink)

const SOURCE = "a.txt"
const DESTINATION = "b.txt"

function init() {
  console.info("Running operation")

  const sourceStream = fs.createReadStream(SOURCE)
  const destinationStream = fs.createWriteStream(DESTINATION)

  sourceStream.on("close", async () => {
    await unlink(DESTINATION)
    init()
  })

  sourceStream.pipe(destinationStream)
}

init()
```

Upon running, this is what is logged to console:

```
Running operation
Running operation
Running operation
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'D:\Projects\test\b.txt'
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at WriteStream.onerror (_stream_readable.js:690:12)
    at WriteStream.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at lazyFs.open (internal/fs/streams.js:273:12)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:141:20)
```

Even weirder, the amount of times it can run the same operation before throwing the error varies. Sometimes it'll fail after 3, sometimes after 5.

So what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait for the destinationStream to end before reading again. Try doing this:

```
 destinationStream.on("close", async () => {
      await unlink(DESTINATION)
      init()
 })
```

Comment: Is there a reason for this working? I was able to put `unlink` inside the close event on the destination stream as well. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, there's a delay in destinationStream to close after sourceStream. Glad you solved it. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm getting the problem right, perhaps you should look for [`finish`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish) event.

Change this:

```
const sourceStream = fs.createReadStream(SOURCE)
const destinationStream = fs.createWriteStream(DESTINATION)

sourceStream.on("close", async () => {
  await unlink(DESTINATION)
  init()
})

sourceStream.pipe(destinationStream)
```

To this:

```
const sourceStream = fs.createReadStream(SOURCE)
const destinationStream = fs.createWriteStream(DESTINATION)

sourceStream.pipe(destinationStream)
   .on('finish', async () => {
     await unlink(DESTINATION);
     console.log('Done');
     init()
   })
```

Comment: The finish event never fires.

Comment: Are you completely sure finish event not fired? Because it works on my computer. Also, what node.js version do you use?

Comment: It does not fire. It runs the operation once and then exits. I'm on v10.13.0.

Comment: If you want to run the code in loop, just add function invocation. I've edited my response and added `init()` as in your example

Comment: I'd like you to know that I never removed the function invocation. I simply changed the event from "close" to "finish".

Comment: So, now it's clear why the code is not working :) Please, give a try to my solution and copy. You need to add `.on` after pipe, because we listen for `finish` event of writable stream, not readable. @SebastianOlsen

Comment: I've added link to documentation of `finish` event, just copy it here https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish

Comment: Then you should have said that in the first place. I changed `sourceStream.on` to `destinationStream.on` and it does the exact same thing, runs 3-5 times, then errors.

Comment: I find this comment extremely unfit considering I have not shown any sort of emotions in my comments. I did what you asked, it did not work. By bringing this up it seems like you are the one who is getting emotionally distressed by this. I don't think it's fair at all to fault me for saying your solution does not work. I've been doing programming for at least 3 years and I know what I'm doing. I understand streams and events, so I honestly don't think I'm at fault here.